# Allow CORS in Heroku Angular JS APP

Tags: php, angularjs, heroku

I have an Only Angular JS Applications hosted in **Heroku**, it works perfectly, but now, i update the application implementing an `$http request` (for consuming an API), but when i execute the app i get this:

```
 error "(razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin')
 {English: reason: CORS header 'access-control-allow-origin' 
  missing}. (is in spanish)
```

Already tried with PHP headers like:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

but still the same

I will be grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Can you translate the error into English for us? Your overall English is just fine, but most StackOverflow users are English speakers and won't be able to help you if it isn't translated, and even if you do get help from someone it will be less helpful for someone who later gets a similar error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BenHare, You're totally rigtht, i assumed that it was understandable, already edited the post with a translation, English: reason: CORS header 'access-control-allow-origin' missing

Comment: Could you post the PHP code? If you added this header and you're still getting this error, the header is most likely not applied. You can confirm this by pressing F12 in your browser and checking the request.

Comment: Hi @Bv202 , thanks for your answer, As i said, i deployed the app in Heroku, but it's only Angular JS, for backend i'm using Firebase. In the Angular JS deployment tutorial says that only an index.php file must be created for redirect the index.html, so the file (index.php) only contains one line that is: "include_once("index2.html"); 
", in this file(index.php) is where i added the headers, but is not working

Comment: @SebasPinto — You have to add the headers to the URL you are requesting with Ajax, not the URL of the HTML document hosting the page the Ajax runs inside.